# Deleting messages with Telethon fails silently

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to delete a comment to a post in a public Telegram channel using Telethon.
I am using the following code:
`client.delete_messages(entity=-int(message['chat_id']), message_ids=[int(message['message_id'])])`
It works for one channel and not the other. The only difference between the channels is who is the creator: deletion works for the one that I created, but not for the one created by another user.
How can I then delete the comment in the public Telegram channel that was created by another user?

Details:
Both channels are public. For both, the bot is added as an adminstrator with the rights to delete messages. There is no error/exception after the deletion code, it just changes nothing in the channel.
I also tried passing the id without the minus, tried getting the channel entity and passing that, tried DeleteMessagesRequest; doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps users who are down voting can put a reason as to why they down vote this question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The specific problem is the silent failure of the deletion on the channel that has the same access rights for the bot as the channel on which the method works, which is exactly what I described.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Telethon, but I recently used Discord's API. Have you eliminated the possibility of insufficient permissions? In Discord, you have to specifically declare the rights that the bot will have, and users will be asked when adding the bot to their servers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I did check the rights of the bot in both channels, they are identical and sufficient, it is an admin and allowed to delete messages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, comments in Telegram happen in the "comments-chat" linked from the main broadcast channel. So if you're trying to delete a message with the pair `(channel_id, msg_id)`, it won't work, because `channel_id` is the broadcast channel and not where the comments are.

In v1, [`GetDiscussionMessageRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_discussion_message.html) can be used to fetch where the right chat is:

```py
r = await client(functions.messages.GetDiscussionMessageRequest(
    peer=channel_id,
    msg_id=msg_id,
))
m = min(r.messages, key=lambda msg: msg.id)
chat = next(c for c in r.chats if c.id == m.peer_id.channel_id)
...
# chat is now the linked chat, and m is the top-level reply "discussion message"
# now you can use delete_messages with this chat and the right message id
```